# Build optimal dictionary algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dictionary

So I had a large plain text script in ASCII, which can have 256 entries from dictionary. Dictionary can contain any string with length 3-6 letters. Each entry takes 2 bytes in script (instead of appropriate dictionary string length).

I had a lot of thought about building optimal dictionary for such scheme. Naive solution is to build any 6-letters substrings at each position, then count each of them and find most frequent. Then exclude this substring from initial script and repeat searching for most frequent for the second most frequent entry.
All of this looks ugly, I believe, there are already serious mathematics behind this task, but I couldn't find any references on that anywhere.
Could you please direct me or describe possible algorithm for mentioned task?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding this?

Comment: No. Huffman coding apply to per-character encoding by analysing it's frequency in text.
In my case I just want to analyze frequency of all substrings in my text and find most frequent.

Comment: You have limited number of possible strings (256). Threat these strings as characters. That means, you will have alphabet with 256 characters.

Comment: Yes, but how can I build an alphabet then? How should I find that A is a concrete substring "banana"?

Comment: This sounds like compression, which is a huge field with many decades' worth of approaches and algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was an MTE codes building algorithm. It was implemented in couple of tools, for instance [here](http://www.romhacking.net/utilities/924/) (C code is also available inside).

The idea behind is a brute force: just like I've described. The importand addition is that when you find best code possible, you also need to count actual MTE code length and take into account only saved length minus MTE codes length, which will be taken.